# What's the difference between jackson-core-asl and jackson-core-lgpl

Tags: java, jackson

Any difference if we want to build commercial software?

Comment: That's a legal question, not a programming one.

Comment: I've been curious about how the lgpl affects Java code as well--is class loading considered dynamic linking?

Comment: @Matthew yes, that and inheritance are both considered the same as linking I believe, and FSF confirms that. Others might disagree though.

Comment: @Matthew the license itself doesn't make that distinction (they're both derived works). However, some people interpret the license differently from others and even from FSF. Better to use the ASL and be safe.

Comment: On a pedantic note, the FSF would remind you that even the GPL has no restrictions on commercial software per se--you just have to distribute the source if you decide to distribute the product.

Comment: From a technical perspective, inheritance at the Java source code level *results in* a dependency on the superclass / interface that requires linking to the corresponding .class file at runtime.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to build commercial software, use the Apache license version. It's a more permissive license than LGPL, so you won't run into any problems using Jackson under the Apache license in your proprietary work provided you follow every term of the Apache license (all are very reasonable). The main difference is that the LGPL might require you to make your application open-source under certain use cases and the Apache license will not.

Depending on your use case the LGPL version might also be usable but the Apache license is a safer bet.

Comment: Commercial software should stay clear of LGPL at all costs, especially when you could argue that jackson is generating code and thus you are using LGPL code to generate some of your code base, thus all of your code base must be LGPL.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I don't know why anyone would choose the LGPL in a commercial context when the Apache license was also an option. But it was asked, so...

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy - where did you get the idea that generated code inherits the license of whatever generated it? If that was true, then you couldn't use gcc to build anything that wasn't GPL.

Comment: @MeBigFatHGuy all your code base are belong to us

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to read the licenses yourself to know which one to use:

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html

The LGPL version will require you to pass along the source code to the library, the Apache version will not. It's up to you to decide which license is a better match for your project.